# Fund transfer from Stripe account to third party bank(e.g.ICICI bank) in php

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm trying to implement transfer stripe fund to third party bank, i'm using Stripe connect.

I'm reading documentation for "Charging through the platform" and it says:

```
require_once('Stripe/lib/Stripe.php');
    Stripe::setApiKey("PLATFORM_SECRET_KEY");


  $charge =Stripe_Charge::create(array(
  'amount' => 1000,
  'currency' => 'usd',
  'source' => $_POST['stripeToken']
   )
  , array('stripe_account' => CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID));
```

I have the PLATFORM_SECRET_KEY, and the TOKEN, but what is the needed CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID?

Do I missed something from the flow?

Is there a way to create a CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID from the user account?

Comment: Hi Varun. You cannot use Stripe to directly send funds to any bank account. The bank account's owner must also have a Stripe account, and this account must be connected to your account ("the platform") so you can accept charges on their behalf. I would recommend reading the Connect documentation from the start: https://stripe.com/docs/connect